# How to auto-generate code based on the current date that the item has been registered?

Tags: php

I am a beginner with very low basic knowledge, but I've been given one task to complete. Now my question is, how to create the auto-generated button to create an unique code? I found something on the Internet which is similar to my question : [Generate Random Number in Textfield Once We Click The Button](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/466085/generate-random-number-in-textfield-once-we-click-the-button) and already tried it but it doesn't work.

Can you guys help me to find the idea? Or give some useful guide for me?

Comment: is the number based only on the time/date? so it will always be the same for the same time and date?, also sounds like you mean front end not backend.. so JS not PHP

Comment: ty for respond, @haxxxton . What if i want to put some letters before the date? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a unique-ish number, then

var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
would get you a simple number. But if you need the readable version, you're in for a bit of processing:

```
var now = new Date();
timestamp  = "Test";
timestamp += now.getFullYear().toString(); // 2014
timestamp += (now.getFullMonth < 9 ? '0' : '') + now.getFullMonth().toString();  
timestamp += (now.getDate < 10) ? '0' : '') + now.getDate().toString();// pad with a 0
... etc... with .getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(), getMilliseconds()
```

Comment: Great, its helpful and working. Worried why Alina has not market it right till now

Comment: If i want to put some letters like A-(current date) , how can i do that? @ashokhein

Comment: @Alina Updated in answer.check it

Comment: @Alina - Accept the answer, if it worths. :)